# Axios multipart/form-data request sent as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: javascript, axios, multipartform-data

I'm attempting to send a multipart/form-data request from a react application to a backend api. When the request is submitted the Content-Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

[image]

I tried a few different things including switching from put to putForm. Which, does change the content-type to multipart/form-data, but doesn't include the boundary which causes the api to reject it.

```
import axios from "axios";
import getEnvironment from "../constants/environments";

export const register = async (request: FormData) => {
    return axios.put(`${getEnvironment.BaseUri}/email/register`, request);
}
```

Comment: What version of Axios? Some had problems with this

Comment: @Phil "axios": "^1.1.3",

Comment: Try setting the content type

Comment: Yep, that's a bad one. Recommend you update to 1.4.0 or even better, ditch Axios entirely and use the Fetch API

Comment: @DanielA.White that is unnecessary and usually incorrect because you need to get the mime boundary token correct. It's best to let your browser handle it

Comment: @Phil thank you so much!! I spent all weekend on this issue!

Comment: Axios is terrible (416 current open issues), poorly tested, constantly breaks semantic versioning and is generally unnecessary. If you need Axios-like functionality such as interceptors and defaults, I suggest you check out [ky](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ky)

Comment: For reference ~ https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4631

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about a (solved) bug in a particular version of Axios

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The resolution was that the axios version 1.1.3 had a bug. I upgraded to 1.4.0

Thank you @Phil for pointing it out!